# Can't bind to 'ngModel' although importing { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

Tags: angular, binding, angular-ngmodel

here is the component.html <input [(ngModel)]="email" (keyup.enter)="onKeyUp()">
here is the error: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

here is my app.module where is imported and added FormsModule

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesServices } from './courses.services';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer/customer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [CoursesServices],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: has you "re-start" the ng serve?

Comment: Try to add `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` with `ngModel`

Comment: yes I restarted ng serve but didn't help

Comment: Are you using import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms'; inside your .component.ts?

Comment: yes, but the error is still there